# Maven on Windows Subsystem For Linux

Tags: maven, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run maven on Windows Subsystem for Linux, and getting "cannot allocate memory" errors. However, *free -m* shows that I have plenty of memory available, and the same build on Cygwin succeeds.

Anyone have any tips for dealing with this? I'd prefer to change my settings.xml over my pom.xml's, but I'm open to almost anything.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Why the close and down votes? Is this question not general enough? Useful? Related to development? Missing details?

Comment: Strange, am I assuming correctly that you use the default JVM options? Can you check that you did not modify anywhere the `Xms`and `Xmx` options and that they are not above your system's resources? (see http://maven.apache.org/configure.html) Also could you post the exact error that you see? And what version of maven you are using?

Comment: How much memory is it trying to allocate? Maybe it's related to a [bug they have](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/631).

Comment: Some answers - first of all, I didn't change the default JVM options, and I was using the default maven from the repositories. However, I did an update (from within WSL) and now I can't replicate this problem - the build succeeds. Maybe the bug that @kichik mentioned was the culprit - that does make some sense.

Answer (score 9):

Try to install maven by downloading it, not by doing an `apt-get install maven`.  On my Ubuntu machines I've never been able to get the "apt" version to work right and have always resorted to downloading it directly from the [Maven download](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) instead.  I tried that on my WSL and was able to build a pretty good sized JEE project with no issues.